# VBA Toggle Button Hide State (active or not)

Tags: excel, vba, toggle, togglebutton

Trying to use a Toggle Button inside a Userform in Excel. I'm using a VBA Code to change the background color, when the button is active or not, but besides that, there's an "animation", when the button is pressed (active), and I don't want that. Is there a way to only change the background color when I press the toggle button?

The image shows
1 - button not active
2 - button active with background color
3 - button the way I want it to be when active

[image]